# Silex routing (pluralization)

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing, silex

If I have a silex route like:

```
$app->get('/project/{projectName}', function (Request $request, $projectName) use ($app) {
   return $projectName;
})
->value('projectName', 'all')
->bind('project');
```

Why can't I define another route like:

```
$app->get('/projects', ...)
->bind('projects');
```

Whenever I try to access the `/projects` route I get redirected to `/projects/` and shown an error message (`NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /projects/"`).

Is there some pluralization logic under the hood that prevents this or what else could be interfering here? (When renaming the second route to anything else it works just fine, so there is something specific to this project/projects naming, I assume.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really strange. I tried this:

```
    $app->get('/project/{projectName}', function (Request $request, $projectName) use ($app) {
   return $projectName;
})
->value('projectName', 'all')
->bind('project');


$app->get('/projects', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return 'TEST';
})
->bind('projects');
```

And calling **/projects** in the browser works for me. I get 'TEST' printed. This should work. Check your strings, maybe you misspelled something.

**EDIT 19.09.2013 **

You may also consider modifying your route matching by regular expressions. For this you can use the `assert` method. Here is an example:

```
$app->get('/{value}', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
    return 'TEST';
})
->bind('projects')
->assert('value', '(projects)/{0,1}');
```

By using this method, I get 'TEST' when opening  both **/projects** and **/projects/**. It all depends on what you want to achieve. Another helpful article might be [How to allow slashes in routes (from the Symfony documentation)](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html)

Comment: Hm, thanks for checking it out. Could it be this is an apache setting, because the error I get is `NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /projects/"`, i.e. it tries to retrieve the projects route with a trailing slash. Yours does not get automatically redirect to the "projects" with the ending slash, or does it? What happens if you manually set the slash?

Comment: I don't get an auto-redirect. When I open /projects/ I get the Exception you described. When I call /projects (without the slash) I get 'TEST' printed. Another thing that can help is editing the route matching by using the assert method - check the edition of my response